# What if you don't activate Windows 7? Which features won't be available to you?

Tags: windows-7

What if you don't activate Windows 7? Which features won't be available to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 activation period](http://superuser.com/questions/108949/windows-7-activation-period)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the Windows version so I've adjusted this answer for more versions than just Windows 7.

Windows Vista RTM has a reduced functionality mode where you'll only get access to a web browser to purchase a key (you can still explore the filesystem and launch most apps using the browser window). Time-limited to 1 hour. The 30 day grace period can be extended 3 times using rearm.

Windows Vista SP1 removed the browser limitation and let you use the entire desktop for 1 hour.

This mode was in Windows 7 as well but was apparently scrapped before final release. Preview releases enters this mode after the preview period expire.

Windows 7, 8.0 and 8.1 uses a desktop background watermark, a notification every hour and removal of your wallpaper. Optional Windows updates won't download and some settings are disabled. You'll still receive security updates and there's no actual time-limit anymore.

In Windows 10 personalization settings will be unavailable and a watermark will show on the desktop background. However, there aren't any popups every hour. Personalization settings can be changed using various other means, with some sources stating they will even sync using your Microsoft account.

Comment: I read somewhere that it auto-restarts every hour or something like that as well, not sure if that's still accurate though.

Comment: I have never seen that the start menu and task bar disappears. Perhaps this was true in 2009 when you answered, but not anymore?

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by "If its only the first 30 days (...)". That sounds like it is only possible to rearm within the first 30 days; that means before the end of the activation deadline. However, I remember successfully rearming after the deadline. But I could have misunderstood something.

Comment: I meant if you had already done rearm. But I've updated the answer to reflect most Windows versions.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to use the operating system, but it will mark itself as *Not Genuine*. The Desktop will be black, you'll receive popups reminding you to activate and you will only receive critical updates.

Answer (score 0):

A Windows 7 installation in Reduced functional mode (notice the watermark at the right hand corner).
If you don’t activate your Windows software
- You will be prompted every time you log in to Activate.
- You will receive periodic prompts to activate your software.
- Certain visual experiences will be disabled such as the Windows Aero Glass theme.
- Won't be able to update software such as Microsoft Security Essentials.
Activate Windows 7 on this computer:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/activate-windows-7-on-this-computer

Comment: Your link goes to generic Windows 10 information.  One might get the impression that Microsoft would prefer that people upgrade to Windows 10.