# What is restricted in Win7 Reduced functionality mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 activation period](https://superuser.com/questions/108949/windows-7-activation-period)

I've got a copy of win7 ultimate which I installed on my newly built PC. 2 Days later, the SSD I was using as a system drive failed.

I've put an old HDD in to run the PC while the SSD is off for repair/replacement - unfortunately, it took me 3 weeks to send it off and I'm not likely to get it back for another 10-14 days.

As I don't intend to keep this installation of Win7, I didn't enter the software key - why waste an activation?

Yesterday, Windows entered reduced functionality mode.

The only chanegs I've noted so far are:

- Windows Update is limited
- Microsoft Security Essentials refuses to update
- I get a very annoying window almost every time I switch between apps
- I see a new dialog when logging in telling me I may be a victim of software piracy
- I get a "This copy of windows is not genuine" on my wallpaper

Does anyone know what else is disabled/crippled? Should I just bite the bullet and activate, then argue with MS over the phone if I can't activate the new installation in 2 weeks time?

If there's nothing else disabled, I may as well live with it until then...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also reset the trial period, to a maximum of 120 days.

1: open cmd.exe as administrator

2: type `slmgr -rearm` and press enter

3: restart the PC.

This should last you until the SSD returns from the manufacturer.

Comment: Very nice, thank you - I'm going to leave this open for a little while as I'm curious if anyone knows any other restrictions but that's exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: It is indeed not an answer to your question, but it will solve the issue ;)

Comment: I'm not going to complain if you go a step further in helping me :D I've just rearmed and interestingly, windows is fine but Security Essentials is still complaining my copy doesn't pass WGA - but I can live with that for a fortnight with no problems.

Comment: @Basiclife:  Security Essentials will always refuse to update unless it passes WGA. That's the price you pay for free and considering it is one of the best if not the best out there.